# how to do profile based operations in gstuil while copying files from S3 to GCS?

Tags: boto, gcloud, gsutil

In AWSCLI we can create profiles in .boto file and we can switch profiles while doing operations like cp, ls, mv etc. How to do the same profile based operations in gsutil tool? I can added access_key and secrect_key information in /etc/boto.cfg but how to add profiles section and how to use it?

```
gsutil cp s3://<bucket-name>/ gs://<bucket-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want functionality similar to AWS named profiles for gcloud you can use gcloud [named configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations). Command details [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations/).